# how to split column content when exporting tables in datatbles

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my datatables there is a column named `serial number` which is in format `ab123`, and for exporting i am using following code,

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "dom": 'Bfrtip',

    "buttons": [
        {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                text: 'download',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
                },
                title: 'exported'
            }
    ]
} );
```

now, in according to current code when i export i get exactly the same content of table, but what i want is get `serial number` as 2 diffrent columns in exported report namely `serial` and `number`. ie original `serial number = ab123` as `serial = ab` and `number = 123`.

i have found tutorial given on https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html

also when i tried doing according to above tutorial, i faced at `$.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {` saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

but i am not sure wheather it will allow me to split the column?
what should i do here? thank you for your suggestions